# iOS crash on Starting Background Task

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibackgroundtask

I've recently revisited my app which was last built for iOS 8.4 and now updating it to 9.3. It was working fine the first few times I ran it but now crashes on every open, across each simulator with the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=50)

```
-(void)beginBackgroundUpdateTask
{
  if (self.backgroundTaskAgent == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
   {
     self.backgroundTaskAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
     }];
   }
}
-(void)endBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    if (self.backgroundTaskAgent != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskAgent];
        self.backgroundTaskAgent = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}
```

The crash occurs in the top method with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler. I've never had this error before and can't find any solution to it myself or on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 -(void)beginBackgroundUpdateTask
{
  self.backgroundTaskAgent == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

  self.backgroundTaskAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
 }];

}
 -(void)endBackgroundUpdateTask
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskAgent];
    self.backgroundTaskAgent = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

 }
```

Comment: Fantastic, that fixed it thanks very much. What was causing the error then?

Comment: your bg task must be invalidate before begin it again!